# Parallel camera planes rectification

Tags: matlab, camera, translation, matlab-cvst

I am doing an experiment in which I have multiple cameras targeted to capture scenes as they are capturing them from a 2D plane. But the problem is their orientation which may change because of some movement and my target is to rectify those orientations only not translation.

I am trying to approach this problem in two ways:

1. I am trying to estimate relative camera pose from MATLAB function and then transforming the second image using T i.e. K*R*K^-1.
2. Second I am trying to address this problem using regular camera rectification problem using estimateUncalibratedRectification. The function return two transformations, T1 and T2, which can be directly used to warp two images. Instead of applying transformation on image separately what I am doing is to only apply transformation on second image and the transformation matrix is T1^-1*T2. My assumptions is that in this way I will have camera orientation equals to 0.

I am verifying if the transformations are correct by observing the farthest feature point which must be near to each other.

What problems I am facing using the first approach is:

Not getting the farthest point to 0.

Please correct my approach.